# What is the most secure way to create login/signup

Tags: android

what is the best dependency they use it in famous apps retrofit or volley or Oauth2 like famous apps

Comment: Most commonly a combination of username/nickname/email and password is used.

Comment: you should elaborate the question I believe. in which terms "professional". did you mean "secure"? -- have a look at this page: https://get.digits.com/blog/introducing-firebase-phone-authentication

Comment: thank you for your submitting  but i meant what use to connect with database  retrofit or volley or Oauth2

Comment: i fix  the title i have my own web server

Comment: Retrofit, Volley or Oauth are not intended to connect with databases. I am still not sure about your question

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: your server is as secure as the information you put on it. depending how you access the data will depend on secure it is. having a web server is one thing, so you can really use PHP to talk to it. but you want to make sure you have a secure connection. if you are worried about user login and stuff like that, make it simple, use firebase, or parse. or you can always create your own API with nodejs and mongodb. again, its as secure as you make it. my advise would be to look for internet security firms, call them, tell them you're doing a report for school and ask them questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use Retrofit2. It is better than volley. Also you can use Rx with retrofit